# Unable to connect to database from rails console on dockers

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, docker, digital-ocean, rails-console

I have my rails project setup on `Digitalocean` using `Dockers`. This is my `docker-compose.prod.yml` file.

```
version: "2"

volumes:
 db-data:
   external: false

services:
 db:
  image: postgres
  env_file: .env.production
 volumes:
   - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

app:
 build: .
 env_file: .env
 environment:
   RAILS_ENV: production
 ports:
   - "3000:3000"
 depends_on:
   - db
```

and this is my `database.yml` file

```
default: &default
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 host: db
 username: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_USER"] %>
 password: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"] %>
 # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
 # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
 pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
 <<: *default
 database:  project_development

test:
 <<: *default
 database: project_test

production:
 <<: *default
 host: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_HOST"] %>
 database: project_production
```

I have created two `docker` images. One for `app` and one for `postgres/db`.

My `application` is working fine on production. I am able to create and delete records from my `web` page on production.

But, when I try to access rails console of `production database` from docker bash by following commands:

```
docker run -i -t project_app:latest bash
```

to access console:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```

Inside `Rails Console` whenever I try to access any `model` data or try to perform any query(`i.e Model.first` etc) I am unable to access `postgres` database. It shows me following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have tried many possible solutions to resolve this issue but unable to resolve this.

Please help me! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying alot at last I found a solution. I was using `docker run -i -t project_app:latest bash` command to access `container` and to run `rails console` command which was wrong.

The correct command to access `container`'s terminal is

```
 docker exec -it project_app /bin/bash
```

After accessing `terminal` I was able to successfully run `query` i.e `User.first` inside `rails console`.

Answer (score 0):

Here: `docker run -i -t project_app:latest bash` you are not providing the env vars that your application need to use as credentials.

So use your docker-compose that is already setting env vars here:

```
env_file: .env
```

So run as this:

```
docker run --env-file .env -i -t project_app:latest bash
```

Comment: When, I use this command, I am getting following error:

`PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known`

Comment: It seems that you need to start the hole docker-compose stuff. It's simple: `docker-compose up -d` then `docker-compose exec app bash`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Docker compose is already started. Conatiners are already working. But in rails console of environment production. I am unable to access data. for example If I run any command like `User.first` it shows me error
`PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known`

Comment: If the containers are already running, just get into them, as this: `docker-compose exec app bash` or `docker exec -it container-id bash`

Comment: I can enter into `containers` and `rails c` but I am unable to query database.
'User.first' etc shows me error that I have mentioned above